# Python: Separating different parts of a string into an array

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I'm trying to separate values (in between the commas) in a string into an list. This is what I have so far:

```
x = ["1,2,3,4,5,", "6,7,8,9,10,"]
x_new = []

for j_1 in range(len(x)):

    y = 0

    for j_2 in range(0, len(x[j_1])):

        if x[j_1][j_2] == ",":
            x_new.append(j_1, (x[j_1][y: j_2]))

            y = j_2 + 1
print("x_new[0] = ", x[0])
print("x_new[1] = ", x[1])
```

All I get is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    x_new.append(j_1, (x[j_1][y: j_2]))
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

I want the code to output:

- x[0] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
- x[1] = ["6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

x will always be separated into 5 strings.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, first, there's no way it's going to output `x[0] = ` anything when you `print("x_new[0] = ", …)`. And if you `print` the original `x` members instead of `x_new` members, you're going to get the original values that you never changed.

Comment: But meanwhile, the `append` error means exactly what it says. I don't understand what values you're _trying_ to pass here. If you want to append the index and the string, you can append a single tuple with those two members. But you don't seem to want that. What's the index doing there at all;?

Comment: Finally, why are you trying to reinvent the wheel in the first place? Python comes with a `split` method: `x_new = [s.split(',') for s in x]`.

Comment: @abarnert: `s.strip(',').split(',')` for this specific scenario (otherwise you'll get an extra `""`); otherwise I fully agree.

Comment: apart from the obvious `split`, read the error. `append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)` tells you that you are calling the function with an incorrect number of parameters. That should tell you to read the documentation for the function to see why what you assumed is wrong. Which should also tell you how to use that function, and to solve the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at what's wrong with your code.

First, the variable names make it really hard to follow. Why do you have `j_1` and `j_2` instead of just, say, `i` and `j`? For that matter, why do you have `j_1` *at all* instead of just iterating over `x` directly?

But anyway, here's your main problem:

```
x_new.append(j_1, (x[j_1][y: j_2]))
```

This call doesn't make any sense. The [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method only takes one argument, a new element to append to the end of the sequence. You're passing it two arguments. Also, you're appending it to `x_new`, which is supposed to be a list of two lists, not into the appropriate sub-list. I *think* what you want here is:

```
x_new[j_1].append(x[j_1][y: j_2])
```

But, before you can do that, you'll also need to actually create each sublist to append onto.

And then, at the end, Python can't guess what you wanted it to print out; if you ask it to print the string `x_new[0]` instead of `x[0]`, or to print out the contents of `x[0]` instead of the contents of `x_new[0]`, that's what you're going to get.

So:

```
x = ["1,2,3,4,5,", "6,7,8,9,10,"]
x_new = []

for j_1 in range(len(x)):
    x_new.append([])
    y = 0    
    for j_2 in range(0, len(x[j_1])):
        if x[j_1][j_2] == ",":
            x_new[j_1].append(x[j_1][y: j_2])

            y = j_2 + 1

print("x[0] =", x_new[0])
print("x[1] =", x_new[1])
```

However, this is all way overcomplicating this. Python strings have a `split` method. So, you can replace this entire mess with:

```
x_new = [s.rstrip(',').split(',') for s in x]
print("x[0] =", x_new[0])
print("x[1] =", x_new[1])
```

The `rstrip(',')` is to remove the trailing comma, so you don't get an extra empty string at the end. You could instead use `s.split(',')[:-1]` or various other means of getting the same effect.

Comment: Thank you not only answering my question, but telling everything else that I did wrong. I'm new to python so I really appreciate it! Also, I never knew that there was a split method so that explains the over complication of the code.

Answer (score 1):

A nested conditional list comprehension can achieve your desired result:

```
x_new = [[i for i in s.split(",") if i] for s in x]
>>> x_new
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']]
```

Comment: Not sure the reason for the down vote since it succinctly answered exactly what the OP requested.  Would the coward who down voted without providing comments care to reply?

Comment: I don't see a problem with it, either, except I'd remove the `!= ''`. Anyway, have my upvote.

Comment: You may notice the original list ends with "5," which results in the last item being parsed as "".  That is why the `!= ''` is needed. Thx.

Comment: Huh? No, there's really no point in testing `!= ''` here. The simple `if i` is enough. Please just try it and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong because you are using "append" incorrectly. There is a better way of doing this, using split function:

```
x = ["1,2,3,4,5,", "6,7,8,9,10,"]
x_new = []

for j in range(len(x)):
    x_new.append([y for y in x[j].split(',') if len(y)>0])

print("x_new[0] = ", x_new[0])
print("x_new[1] = ", x_new[1])
```

Reasoning: for each element in the list do a split and discard empty elements (assuming you got a ',' at the end. Seems to give the result you want.

The remaining "for" can be replaced by another list comprehension:

```
x = ["1,2,3,4,5,", "6,7,8,9,10,"]
x_new = [[y for y in x[j].split(',') if len(y)>0] for j in range(len(x))]
```

If you want to keep the style of your code, this is a fixed version:

```
x = ["1,2,3,4,5,", "6,7,8,9,10,"]
x_new = []

for j_1 in range(len(x)):
    y = 0
    x_new_aux = []
    for j_2 in range(len(x[j_1])):
        if x[j_1][j_2] == ",":
            x_new_aux.append(x[j_1][y:j_2])
            y = j_2+1
    x_new.append(x_new_aux)

print("x_new[0] = ", x_new[0])
print("x_new[1] = ", x_new[1])
```

Notice I'm using a auxiliary list.

Answer (score 1):

```py
x = ["1,2,3,4,5,", "6,7,8,9,10,"]
new_list = [x[i].split(',')[:-1] for i in range(len(x))]
>>
 new_list = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']]
```